# How to monitor for new/removed serial device connections without lagging program?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I have a GUI on a raspberry pi that sends data to a few connected arduinos. I used to hardcode the common serial port names /dev/ttyACM1 and such but some other boards have different device IDs so I found some code that just checks all the serial ports.

Basically, the code receives some updated telemetry and tries to send all of it (roughly 300 characters) out to any and all arduinos connected to the raspberry pi.

The new code is great and removes 300 lines of my hardcoded nonsense but the program is lagging a lot now when transmitting the data and I suspect it's related to looking for every serial device every second.

Basically, I'm just looking for input on the best way to accomplish my goals.

```
def serial_ports():
    ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            result.append(port)
            #s.close() #do I need to close the port each time
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException) as e:
            pass
    return result

def serialWrite(*args): #
    logWrite("Function call - serial write: " + str(*args))
    for port in serial_ports():
        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, write_timeout=0, timeout=0)
            ser.write(str.encode(*args))
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException) as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

The serialWrite function is called about 13 times per second, I supposed I should probably group all the data and just call the function once? Still new to all this

Any advice on automatically adding new serial devices that get plugged in and account for devices being removed while the program is running without doing anything unnecessarily taxing to the program?

Comment: you can use udev rules to always mount it as a specific device, and even to call a script when it is connected ... you could also do your loop in a thread separate from the main thread

Comment: @JoranBeasley oh interesting, I hadn't heard of that before. That's a good solution, but we intend to distribute the program to a bunch of people so it would be good for the solution to be completely contained with the program. I like the separate thread idea, I'll look into that though. Thanks!

Comment: You might also look at using the [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) API to get events when files are created. There are confusingly several python libraries providing this API. I don't know them well. Example: [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial)